# SharePoint (MOSS) hosting with custom code allowed

Tags: sharepoint, hosting, moss

I'm looking for a SharePoint (MOSS) shared hosting provider that supports deployment of custom solutions (.WSPs) - it'd be okay if it was medium trust. I'm building a public Internet site on SP and the client doesn't want to host it or pay for the license all up front. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it matter which country the hosting provider is in?

Comment: Alex: Not directly, but the latency needs to be pretty low and North American throughput high.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any shared hosting plans that support the deployment of custom solutions.  From what I've seen, you'd need at least a semi-dedicated hosting plan.  I'm a developer at Fpweb.net and I know that you can do this using any of their [semi-dedicated plans](http://www.fpweb.net/moss-hosting/moss-corporate.asp).

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to develop a custom Sharepoint Page, you may consider the sharepoint plan at [ASPHostPortal.com](http://www.asphostportal.com). They allow not only medium trust, but full trust mode and this certainly allow you to create a custom page via any Sharepoint Designer tool that you may have.